# How to change the cell color of HTML table according to a threshold

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql query as below in my php page,

```
$query = "
select table_date as Date,vals as Value from usertable.table1 group by table_date;";
```

I am fetching data to columns from below method.

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
{
    $q2Date .= '<td style="text-align:center"><b>'.$row['Date'].'</td>';
    $q2Value .= '<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['Value'].'</td>';
    $row['Date']++;   
}
```

Then I am using `$body`  variable as below to show them in a html table.

```
$body.= '
    <table style="top: 15px; left:10px; " border=1>

        <tbody>
            <caption style="color: rgb(241, 239, 243);background: rgb(1, 32, 65); ">Total Value</caption>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center"><b>Date</td>'.$q2Date  .'
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center"><b>Value</td>'.$q2Value .'
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
';
```

From above method I could get the output as below,

[image]

Now I need to check each cell and change its color if it differs more than 25% from average value(lets say 250). Then the output should show as follows,

[image]

What changes to be done in my original code? Do I need to change my query as well? or HTML or both?

Comment: Just the HTML/PHP primarily - write some php code to change the background style of the cell `if` the value meets your condition. (Of course beforehand you need to have calculated the average.  That could be done with a second query, or by looping through all the rows).

Comment: you can create if statement in **Do While** for check if data more than 25% from average and set **<td>**  background color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if `value` is greater than 250 then set background color style:

```
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
{
    $q2Date .= '<td style="text-align:center"><b>'.$row['Date'].'</td>';
    if($row['Value'] >= 250)
        $q2Value .= '<td style="text-align:center;background-color:red;">'.$row['Value'].'</td>';
    else
        $q2Value .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$row['Value'].'</td>';
    $row['Date']++;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its so simple to create a class in CSS let's say lessCell

```
.lessCell{
background:red;
}
```

then check the value if it is true add the class to  if it's not do nothing

```
$cls="";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
{
if(your_condition==true){
$cls='class="lessCell"';
}else{
$cls=""
}
    $q2Date .= '<td '.$cls.' style="text-align:center"><b>'.$row['Date'].'</td>';
    $q2Value .= '<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['Value'].'</td>';
    $row['Date']++;   
}
```